# MySQLで、あるテーブルa内にある2つのカラムから、他のテーブルbを参照する場合は、1対多になりますか？ left joinでよい？

Tags: mysql

area_masterテーブル
・id 1,area_nameカラム 東京
・id 2,area_nameカラム 名古屋
・id 3,area_nameカラム 大阪

mainテーブル
・id 1,area_idカラム 1
・id 2,area_idカラム 1
・id 3,area_idカラム 2

上記内容だと、1対多なので普通の left joinでよいと思うのですが、
下記のようにmainテーブル内にある2つのカラムから、他のテーブルarea_masterを参照する場合でも、1対多になりますか？
取得する場合の結合は、普通の left joinでよい？

mainテーブル
・id 1,area_a_idカラム 1,area_b_idカラム 1
・id 2,area_a_idカラム 1,area_b_idカラム 2
・id 3,area_a_idカラム 2,area_b_idカラム 3

環境
MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 質問文のER図]

多対1(外部結合を使うということは厳密には`0..1`かと思いますが)が2つある状態です。
外部結合を2回行えばよいです。

```sql
select * from main m
left join area_master a on m.area_a_id = a.id
left join area_master b on m.area_b_id = b.id
```

[playground link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kPhWtzLQJPs1D6S9ZjYHMx/1)